# The statusBar becomes transparent, After set navigationBar Hidden

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, ios7-statusbar

After set `navigationBarHidden=YES`, the `statusBar` becomes `transparent`.

The only way is set statusBar `backgroundcolor=white?` (Actually it works...)

[image]

Comment: usually I would create a top constraint and set the constraint constant to device status bar height. Noted iphonex has a different status bar height than others.

Comment: @Surely could you show me an example?

Comment: If you are using storyboard, you can set a top to superview constraint, and then drag this constraint to your view controller. In viewDidLoad, you can update the constraint's contant value to device status bar height. For example: topConstraint.constant = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height.     If you are not using storyboard, you can set the top most view's frame's y value to the status bar height value.

Comment: "set the top most view's frame's y value to the status bar height value"  if  set the y value ,the status bar will be blocked by the view?  @Surely

Comment: no the whole idea is to have your views below status bar.

Comment: Thank you @Surely Finally , I draw the view below the statusbar. As you  say  set y position and height

Answer (score 1):

You can use below trick:

```
func setStatusBarColor() {
        if #available(iOS 13, *)
        {
            let keyWindow = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes
                    .filter({$0.activationState == .foregroundActive})
                    .compactMap({$0 as? UIWindowScene})
                    .first?.windows
                    .filter({$0.isKeyWindow}).first
            let statusBar = UIView(frame: (keyWindow?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame) ?? CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: statubarHeight))
            statusBar.backgroundColor = .white //your color
            keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBar)
        } else {
            let statusBar: UIView = UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView
            if statusBar.responds(to:#selector(setter: UIView.backgroundColor)) {
                statusBar.backgroundColor = .white //your color
            }
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
        }
    }
```

and also you can use:

```
yourController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: Well yeah, this allows us to colorize status bar. And it's also a hackish,  we grab `statusBar` object using KVC. It's not problematic for this example (cause its known its 'valid' and won't crash on iOS 13 and less), but generally not good recommendable.

Comment: Anyway, I haven't explained precisely what I was trying to achive. I will accept this, cause its a possible solution anyway. I will make another question where I will explain problem in detail, and post here a link if You want to peek (cause its actually similar but the the same is OP's original question)

Comment: Here is the link to my question related to this : https://stackoverflow.com/q/71329167/3402095